# How to Extracting data from dictionary column?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I have dataframe with two columns, date and Details. My details column cantinas dictionary in every cell and i have to get two values from this dictionary and store it in its own cell column.

```
Date    Details
6/14/2022   {"number":"1","name":"John"}
6/15/2022   {"number":"2","name":"Steve"}
6/16/2022   {"number":"3","name":"Mira"}
6/17/2022   {"number":"17","name":"John"}
6/18/2022   {"number":"4","name":"Larry"}
6/19/2022   {"number":"33","name":"Bob"}
6/20/2022   {"number":"43","name":"james"}
6/21/2022   {"number":"112","name":"Joe"}
```

So what i need to get is dataframe with column Date as it is, column Number with numbers extracted from Details dictionary and column Name with names extracted from the Details dictionary.

I tried using these methods:
1.

```
df['Name'] = list(df['Details'].keys())[0]
```

This produces column names with all zeros in it which is wrong

2.

```
df['Name'] = df['Details'].apply(lambda x: x.get([0]))
```

This approach gives me error: AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'get'

3.

```
df['Name'] = df['Details'].get([0])
```

This give me NaN

Any suggestions on how should i go about this?

Comment: If not, can you be more specific what failed?

Comment: Yeah those i tried didn't work.

Comment: I check dupe answers and there is no method posted in question, do you try them?

Comment: Jezrael - i added the specific on each attempt with what went wrong and what error i was getting.

Comment: Do you try `df['Details'] = df['Details'].apply(ast.literal_eval)` and then `df['Name'] = df['Details'].str.get('name')` ?

Comment: They keep closing my question as dups but the one they suggest i check they dont solve my issue.

Comment: New dupe was added with 13 answers, I hope find solution for it.

Comment: Also for me working `df = df.join(pd.json_normalize(df['Details'].apply(ast.literal_eval)))`

Comment: `pd.concat([df.drop(['details'], axis=1), df['details'].apply(pd.Series)], axis=1)` => It's simple to achieve your requirement.